# How to document a partially applied function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, functools

I have a couple of partially applied functions (`functools.partial`) in my package.  How can I document them?  I have tried setting the `myfunc.__doc__` but that doesn't seem to work.  I would like the documentation to show up when I build the API docs using Sphinx.

An example would be:

```
from collections import deque
from functools import partial

# Consume an iterable
consume = partial(deque, maxlen=0)
consume.__doc__ = "Consume an iterable"
```

Instead of adding a comment in the source file like above, I would like it to show up as a documented function when I generate my API docs using sphinx, or when I import it interactively and call `help(consume)`.  Something like:

```
consume(Iterable)
    Consume an iterable
```

So I updated `__doc__`.  But calling `help(consume)` still shows the docs for `partial`, and Sphinx ignores `consume` altogether (see screenshot)!  This example is trivial, but in my package I also have other cases where there's a lot that can mentioned in the docs, e.g. code examples.

[image]

**Edit**: I guess I have the fallback option to actually write a one-line function wrapper.

Comment: Which version of sphinx are you using?

Comment: @schwobaseggl: The latest from conda-forge: 3.0.3

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: Strange, according to https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/5305/files, the `myfunc.__doc__` approach should be working as of 1.7.7

Comment: I checked interactively, it's something odd with `partial`, eventhough `myfunc.__doc__` is updated, `help(myfunc)` shows the docs for `partial`. :-|.  Edit: I'll try again in a fresh `sphinx` build.

Comment: "Instead of adding a comment in the source file..." Sphinx processes docstrings. Comments are ignored.

Comment: @mzjn: sorry, forgot to include the `__doc__` line in the example, see my edit